# How to remove fully blank lines from text field?

Tags: sql-server, replace, formatting

I've got a data imported from mail messages to a table and sometimes it looks like that:

```
Line 1

Line 2



Line 3
```

What I’d like is for it to look like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Is there any option how to achieve this? I only need to replace fully blank lines to have it presented in a Report Builder with much convenient way.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your text field is varchar, since noone uses text anymore.

A line change is in most cases ascii 13 + ascii 10. By replacing all ascii 10 followed by ascii 13, you will remove the blank lines (Unless they contain spaces).

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max) =
'Line 1

Line 2


Line 3'

SELECT replace(@x, char(10) + char(13), '')
```

Result:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Proof that this also works on text:

```
create table x(x text)
insert x values(
'LINE1

LINE2


LINE3
')

SELECT replace(cast(x as varchar(max)), char(10) + char(13), '')
FROM x
```

Result:

```
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
```

Comment: unfortunately it's a text type, and even if I convert it with a cast to varchar, it looks like that: http://snag.gy/mbNf6.jpg while almost every sentence from that message was separated with double or triple blank lines.. it would be great if there was a way to remove only fully blank line without anything else

Comment: @janek then cast it to varchar(max), this will remove all fully blank lines

Comment: I did it, my code is ,REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(description as varchar(max)), CHAR(13), '       '), CHAR(10), '       ') as description but it look then as on my screen from the url

Comment: you didn't use my script, there is a big difference from what you wrote to what I wrote

Comment: sorry, I've tried now: || replace(cast(description as varchar(max)), char(10) + char(13), '') as description || but it seems not to work...

Comment: @Janek then you have other data on the "blank" lines. Check my new example in my answer